# Index value from htest object?

Tags: r

Simple little question: Say I've executed a paired t.test() function, it becomes a list, and I get the following when I call it in console:

```
dataFrame_tTest
```

```
data:  dataFrame$vector1 and dataFrame$vector2
t = -1.198, df = 5164, p-value = 0.231
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.031392649  0.007578515
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
            -0.01190707
```

I can index a value like so:

```
dataFrame_tTest$estimate
```

And return:

```
mean of the differences 
            -0.01190707
```

How would one index Dataframe_Test to return just the value, without the "mean of the differences" text that accompanies it here. I've tried [1][1], another $ and so forth, but so far have not figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
unname(dataFrame_tTest$estimate)
```

Or

```
as.numeric(dataFrame_tTest$estimate)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
c(dataFrame_tTest$estimate)
```